# Heuristic decomposition of asymptotic functions

Tags: functions, algorithms, asymptotics, online-resources

I'll be frank, I'm a bit out of my depth with this. That said, I wonder if there is a heuristic method that takes in a set of measurements of an asymptotic function and, from these measurements, is able of infer a decomposition of the asymptotic function into its constituent components.

For example, imagine we have the following data:

$x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]$

$y=[3,12,35,80,157,280,471,768,1241]$

Where the function is:

$f(x) = 2^x + x^3$

Which, asymptotically, would be:

$O(2^n)$

Are there any methods to take in the function evaluations (i.e. $y$) and infer the components driving the dynamics of the function (i.e. $2^x$ and $x^3$). My understanding is that such a method would necessarily be heuristic because the number of functions that might result in the values of $y$ upon input of $x$ is infinite.

Caveat: I may not have the language to search for such a method, but I haven't had much progress using terms like 'decomposition of asymptotic functions.'

Comment: Even though this problem seems quite reasonable, there is no hope  finding a consistent theory dealing with it.  Otherwise, a century of stock market data would allow one to guess tomorrow's stock prices. The most successful attempts at dealing with this are restricted to situations in which the general form of your function is known in advance and all you need to do is estimate a few parameters of said function.

Comment: @Ruy Ah that makes sense. My use case is comparing the complexity of two algorithms on the basis of empirical runtime data, so we can make some rough assumptions about the dynamics (i.e. scaling) from understanding the problem the algorithms are solving. That said, the question in a sense is "can we infer the crucial dynamics of the algorithms runtime and extract them out into constituent components?" Examples of components would be 'core runtime on the basis of the input', 'gains/losses in efficiency due to compiler optimizations', 'influence of some combinatorial parameter, $k$', etc.

Comment: I see!  Perhaps then you should analyze the problem qualitatively and try to come up with an expression like $$f(x)=ab^x+cx^n+...$$ where each term $ab^x$, $cx^n$, and so on, would account for some feature of your algorithm.  Then you could plug in your experimental data and adjust the parameters $a,b,c,n$ in order to minimize the error.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "asymptotic function". What do you mean by that phrase?

Comment: You could try the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C12%2C35%2C80%2C157%2C280%2C471%2C768%2C1241&sort=&language=english&go=Search)

Comment: Or (with a little more data) the [gfun package](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=gfun) in Maple.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Right, so I was loose with my words. What I meant was functions that are the subject of asymptotic analysis (e.g. worst case complexity or average case complexity of an algorithm).

Comment: @Ruy This is along the lines of another approach I was thinking – least squares fitting of a function. But I'm hesitant because I expect that doing so may strongly violate some assumptions behind the method. I'll dig into this, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @RobertIsrael Woah! OEIS is fascinating, really excited a resource like that exists. I'll have to play with this and see how well populated it is seeing as it seems to be driven by a lookup table rather than an explicit method. gfun looks perfect though! Thanks so much for sharing these!

Comment: But every function can be the subject of an asymptotic analysis.